# URL block based on entity variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, url, spring-security

I am working on a Spring Boot & Spring Security project where a user can add flights to his trip if the trip has been approved (user entity contains a status variable that can be changed by the admin to approved or denied for the trip) by an admin.
As long as the trip has pending/denied status the user should not be able to access the flights url. How can I achieve this blocking functionality based on that user variable?

Trips url: http://localhost:4040/user/{userId}/trip

Flights url for a specific trip: http://localhost:4040/user/{userId}/trips/{tripId}/flights

Comment: Do you want to do it by @PreAutorized?

Comment: @cjgmj Sure, I have some implementations of PreAuthorized in my project, mainly on "hasAuthority('ADMIN')" type of stuff. Would like to know your solution!

Comment: You can create your own method to evaluate the user, so you can get if the user is avable to add flights to his trip. [Here you have an example](http://code-addict.pl/permission-evaluator-boot2/)